# Why is my question getting downvotes?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if anyone would like to answer me, but it seems like everyone is getting annoyed at everything I do.

I asked the question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33535/what-is-the-history-of-synonyms and it has been down-voted.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't see or vote on the question originally, but I can say that it is very unclear what you want.

When you say:

> When synonyms were first used did people know they were called synonyms?

What does this mean exactly?  After all, when synonyms were first used, they *weren't* called "synonyms" — I am quite certain the name came about after the phenomenon.  The title of the question is "history of synonyms", so does this mean you want the history of the word "synonym"?  Or does this mean you want the history of the concept of synonymy?  (If it is the latter, I don't think anyone can give you a concise answer, and it's not exactly an English language question either.)

A question will tend to be downvoted if the question doesn't make sense, if the question seems too obvious, if the question is off-topic, or if the premise is flawed.  Depending on what people assume you meant with your question, they may have downvoted for any of these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you're coming across as someone who wants to be spoon-fed information.

Your question about synonyms was worded very bluntly, and really didn't show any effort at research on your own. You could likely research this in a few minutes on Google or Wikipedia.

I suggest you make at least a token effort at research before posting questions. Also, posting more interesting questions would probably be helpful; you can do this by showing context, such as why you are looking for the answer. Also, telling people what effort you've made to solve this problem so far would help make people more inclined to answer your questions.

Understanding the structure of Stack Exchange in general might also be instructive. (For example, this question was posted on Meta Stack Overflow and then moved here, where it is more appropriate.)